# How to loop a script through a list of tibbles and join them into one tibble?

Tags: r, loops, iteration, purrr

**NOTE: see dputs and script in bottom section**

**Problem Summary**

I have a script I have written that takes a tibble `datainput`, transforms it into a tibble `df`, performs a series of functions / calculations building off of the `df` object, and eventually joins the original `datainput` tibble with `df` to create a new column called `datainput$cluster`

Here is what `datainput` looks like:

```
> head(datainput)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
           p f          x g         
       <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>     
1  409100012 107403 0.005 107403   x
2  409100012 x      0.995 107403   x
3 1032400197 107403 0.05  107403   x
4 1032400197 x      0.95  107403   x
5 3725600001 107403 0.033 107403   x
6 3725600001 x      0.967 107403   x
```

And here is what `datainput` looks like, after applying  the script above:

```
> head(datainput)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
           p f          x g          cluster
       <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>        <int>
1  409100012 107403 0.005 107403   x       1
2  409100012 x      0.995 107403   x       1
3 1032400197 107403 0.05  107403   x       2
4 1032400197 x      0.95  107403   x       2
5 3725600001 107403 0.033 107403   x       2
6 3725600001 x      0.967 107403   x       2
```

**The actual problem I'm facing** is that I need to figure out how to apply this script not to one tibble as the `datainput`, but to as a list of tibbles, called `dfl`. I have tried many variations of lapply, etc., but am not having any luck.

I think my problem lies in how I am storing my script as a function.

Can someone offer any guidance as to how I can apply my script to the list of tibbles in the `dfl` object, and then convert the `dfl` object into one tibble with the new column added?

**dputs**

`datainput`:

```
structure(list(p = c(409100012, 409100012, 1032400197, 1032400197, 
3725600001, 3725600001, 4218200011, 4218200011, 4873700001, 4873700001, 
5305300007, 5305300007, 6488100007, 6488100007, 7008700002, 7008700002, 
7517400002, 7517400002, 8265300001, 8265300001, 8301900001, 8301900001, 
8301900002, 8301900002, 8301900003, 8301900003, 8301900005, 8301900005, 
8301900006, 8301900006, 8313500001, 8313500001, 8534800002, 8534800002, 
8555600001, 8555600001, 8555600002, 8555600002, 8620000001, 8620000001, 
8620000002, 8620000002, 8758300003, 8758300003, 8790700001, 8790700001, 
8790700002, 8790700002, 8896500001, 8896500001, 8916000002, 8916000002, 
8916000004, 8916000004, 9085600001, 9085600001, 9085600002, 9085600002, 
9085600003, 9085600003, 9179900001, 9179900001, 9208200001, 9208200001, 
9441800001, 9441800001, 9565600001, 9565600001, 9565600002, 9565600002, 
9754300001, 9754300001), f = c("107403", "x", "107403", "x", 
"107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", 
"x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", 
"107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", 
"x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", 
"107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", 
"x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", 
"107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", 
"x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x"), x = c(0.005, 0.995, 0.05, 
0.95, 0.033, 0.967, 0.036, 0.964, 0.0512, 0.9488, 0.0075, 0.9925, 
0.036, 0.964, 0.001, 0.999, 0.05, 0.95, 0.0074, 0.9926, 0.84, 
0.16, 0.0075, 0.9925, 0.05, 0.95, 0.05, 0.95, 0.0075, 0.9925, 
0.0144, 0.9856, 0.033, 0.967, 0.05, 0.95, 0.0075, 0.9925, 0.0084, 
0.9916, 0.036, 0.964, 0.005, 0.995, 0.036, 0.964, 0.05, 0.95, 
0.0005, 0.9995, 0.036, 0.964, 0.02, 0.98, 0.036, 0.964, 0.013, 
0.987, 0.005, 0.995, 0.036, 0.964, 0.0075, 0.9925, 0.01, 0.99, 
0.005, 0.995, 0.05, 0.95, 0.005, 0.995), g = c("107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x")), row.names = c(NA, -72L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

`script`:

```
# transform data
df <- 
  pivot_wider( 
    datainput,
    id_cols = "p", 
    names_from = "f", 
    values_from = "x"
  )

rows <- df$p

df <- df %>% select(-p) 

df[is.na(df)] <- 0

row.names(df) <- rows

df <- scale(df)

# compute dissimilarity matrix
d <- dist(df, method = "euclidean")

# store method names in m
m <- c( "average", "single", "complete", "ward")
names(m) <- c( "average", "single", "complete", "ward")

# function to compute coefficients
ac <- function(x) { 
  agnes(d, method = x)$ac
}

# choose best method by coefficient, store in method
coeffs <- map_dbl(m, ac) %>% #
  as_tibble %>%
  mutate(method = m) %>%
  filter(value == max(value))

coeffs <- matrix(data = coeffs)

method = coeffs[2,1]

# Function to compute hierarchical clustering using d and method
hc <- function(x) {
  agnes(d, method = method)
}

# compute hierarchical clustering with optimal method
hc1 <- hc(method)

# determine optimal clusters number by slopes of elbow plot
elbowplot <- fviz_nbclust(df, FUN = hcut, method = "wss")

elbow <- ggplot_build(elbowplot)

elbow <- elbow$data[[1]] %>%
  as_tibble() 

elbow <- elbow %>%
  mutate(slope = if_else(
    elbow$x == min(elbow$x), elbow$y/elbow$x,
    -(elbow$y-lag(elbow$y)/(elbow$x-lag(elbow$x)))
  ))

elbow <- elbow %>%
  mutate(lastslope = if_else(
    x == 1, slope, lag(elbow$slope)
    )) %>%
  mutate(nextslope = if_else(
    elbow$x == max(elbow$x), elbow$slope, lead(elbow$slope)
  )) %>%
  mutate(slopedelta = as.numeric(lastslope - slope)) %>%
  arrange(-slopedelta) %>%
  slice_head() %>%
  select(x)

clusters <- matrix(data = elbow)

clusters = clusters[1,1]

# Cut dendrogram by clusters, store in sub_grp
sub_grp <- cutree(hc1, k = clusters)

# store cluster value as column called cluster
df <- df %>%
  as_tibble()

row.names(df) <- rows

df <- df %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "p") %>%
  mutate(cluster = sub_grp) %>%
  select(p, cluster) %>%
  mutate(p = as.double(p))

datainput <-
  left_join(datainput, df)

# rm unneccesary things
rm(clusters, coeffs, elbow, elbowplot, hc1, method, d, m, rows, sub_grp, ac, hc, df)
```

`dfl`:

```
structure(list(structure(list(p = c(409100012, 409100012, 1032400197, 
1032400197, 3725600001, 3725600001, 4218200011, 4218200011, 4873700001, 
4873700001, 5305300007, 5305300007, 6488100007, 6488100007, 7008700002, 
7008700002, 7517400002, 7517400002, 8265300001, 8265300001, 8301900001, 
8301900001, 8301900002, 8301900002, 8301900003, 8301900003, 8301900005, 
8301900005, 8301900006, 8301900006, 8313500001, 8313500001, 8534800002, 
8534800002, 8555600001, 8555600001, 8555600002, 8555600002, 8620000001, 
8620000001, 8620000002, 8620000002, 8758300003, 8758300003, 8790700001, 
8790700001, 8790700002, 8790700002, 8896500001, 8896500001, 8916000002, 
8916000002, 8916000004, 8916000004, 9085600001, 9085600001, 9085600002, 
9085600002, 9085600003, 9085600003, 9179900001, 9179900001, 9208200001, 
9208200001, 9441800001, 9441800001, 9565600001, 9565600001, 9565600002, 
9565600002, 9754300001, 9754300001), f = c("107403", "x", "107403", 
"x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", 
"107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", 
"x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", 
"107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", 
"x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", 
"107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", 
"x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x", 
"107403", "x", "107403", "x", "107403", "x"), x = c(0.005, 0.995, 
0.05, 0.95, 0.033, 0.967, 0.036, 0.964, 0.0512, 0.9488, 0.0075, 
0.9925, 0.036, 0.964, 0.001, 0.999, 0.05, 0.95, 0.0074, 0.9926, 
0.84, 0.16, 0.0075, 0.9925, 0.05, 0.95, 0.05, 0.95, 0.0075, 0.9925, 
0.0144, 0.9856, 0.033, 0.967, 0.05, 0.95, 0.0075, 0.9925, 0.0084, 
0.9916, 0.036, 0.964, 0.005, 0.995, 0.036, 0.964, 0.05, 0.95, 
0.0005, 0.9995, 0.036, 0.964, 0.02, 0.98, 0.036, 0.964, 0.013, 
0.987, 0.005, 0.995, 0.036, 0.964, 0.0075, 0.9925, 0.01, 0.99, 
0.005, 0.995, 0.05, 0.95, 0.005, 0.995), g = c("107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", "107403   x", 
"107403   x")), row.names = c(NA, -72L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(p = c(50700005, 50700005, 
145900103, 145900103, 183900065, 183900065, 214400008, 214400008, 
546400001, 546400001, 683600191, 683600191, 1032400049, 1032400049, 
7295600001, 7295600001), f = c("128928", "x", "128928", "x", 
"128928", "x", "128928", "x", "128928", "x", "128928", "x", "128928", 
"x", "128928", "x"), x = c(0.4, 0.6, 0.0285, 0.9715, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.1, 0.9, 0.129, 0.871, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.000175, 0.999825
), g = c("128928   x", "128928   x", "128928   x", "128928   x", 
"128928   x", "128928   x", "128928   x", "128928   x", "128928   x", 
"128928   x", "128928   x", "128928   x", "128928   x", "128928   x", 
"128928   x", "128928   x")), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(p = c(125801401, 125801401, 
144800345, 144800345, 170600168, 170600168, 170600181, 170600181, 
170600217, 170600217, 170600235, 170600235, 221400012, 221400012, 
221400013, 221400013, 221400014, 221400014, 221400015, 221400015, 
337700025, 337700025, 337700028, 337700028, 337700029, 337700029, 
337700032, 337700032, 337700034, 337700034, 337700053, 337700053, 
337700054, 337700054, 337700073, 337700073, 337700075, 337700075, 
337700076, 337700076, 337700077, 337700077, 343200058, 343200058, 
343200090, 343200090, 352500127, 352500127, 387600158, 387600158, 
387600159, 387600159, 518500447, 518500447, 518500448, 518500448, 
518500449, 518500449, 518500450, 518500450, 518500451, 518500451, 
518500466, 518500466, 518500467, 518500467, 573600090, 573600090, 
573600094, 573600094, 578500066, 578500066, 578500067, 578500067, 
578500076, 578500076, 578500078, 578500078, 578500079, 578500079, 
578500080, 578500080, 578500081, 578500081, 736400030, 736400030, 
736400104, 736400104, 736400106, 736400106, 736400107, 736400107, 
761600065, 761600065, 862200045, 862200045, 862200049, 862200049, 
862200051, 862200051, 862200057, 862200057, 862200066, 862200066, 
862200067, 862200067, 862200078, 862200078, 862200089, 862200089, 
862200091, 862200091, 895900052, 895900052, 1032400095, 1032400095, 
1530000026, 1530000026, 4126000041, 4126000041, 4154700013, 4154700013, 
4229100003, 4229100003, 4530900043, 4530900043, 4533700006, 4533700006, 
4533700007, 4533700007, 4533700008, 4533700008, 4533700009, 4533700009, 
4533700010, 4533700010, 4533700011, 4533700011, 4533700014, 4533700014, 
4533700015, 4533700015, 4533700016, 4533700016, 4604300027, 4604300027, 
4604300028, 4604300028, 4604300029, 4604300029, 5499800009, 5499800009, 
5861600003, 5861600003, 5861600005, 5861600005, 5861600006, 5861600006, 
6248100001, 6248100001, 6383800026, 6383800026, 6947000031, 6947000031, 
6968100036, 6968100036, 6968100042, 6968100042, 7170400001, 7170400001, 
7177000005, 7177000005, 7357800001, 7357800001, 7465500019, 7465500019, 
7465500029, 7465500029, 8345100017, 8345100017, 8345100018, 8345100018, 
8345100019, 8345100019, 8871400003, 8871400003, 8911000035, 8911000035, 
9005200001, 9005200001), f = c("13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", 
"x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", 
"13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", 
"x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", 
"13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", 
"x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", 
"13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", 
"x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", 
"13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", 
"x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", 
"13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", 
"x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", 
"13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", 
"x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", 
"13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", 
"x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", 
"13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", 
"x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", 
"13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", 
"x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", 
"13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x", "13907", 
"x", "13907", "x", "13907", "x"), x = c(0.98, 0.02, 0.4, 0.6, 
0.428, 0.572, 0.428, 0.572, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.453, 0.547, 
0.4, 0.6, 0.38, 0.62, 0.43, 0.57, 0.4, 0.6, 0.45, 0.55, 0.45, 
0.55, 0.4, 0.6, 0.98, 0.02, 0.98, 0.02, 0.4, 0.6, 0.43, 0.57, 
0.1, 0.9, 0.5, 0.5, 0.98, 0.02, 0.35, 0.65, 0.99, 0.01, 0.3218, 
0.6782, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.97, 0.03, 0.97, 0.03, 0.46, 0.54, 
0.46, 0.54, 0.4, 0.6, 0.38, 0.62, 0.43, 0.57, 0.026, 0.974, 0.017, 
0.983, 0.46, 0.54, 0.46, 0.54, 0.38, 0.62, 0.97, 0.03, 0.428, 
0.572, 0.15, 0.85, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3218, 0.6782, 0.98, 0.02, 0.98, 
0.02, 0.98, 0.02, 0.038, 0.962, 0.99, 0.01, 0.4, 0.6, 0.99, 0.01, 
0.99, 0.01, 0.45, 0.55, 0.43, 0.57, 0.99, 0.01, 0.46, 0.54, 0.45, 
0.55, 0.98, 0.02, 0.98, 0.02, 0.4, 0.6, 0.312, 0.688, 0.99, 0.01, 
0.3218, 0.6782, 0.35, 0.65, 0.223, 0.777, 0.208, 0.792, 0.888, 
0.112, 0.485, 0.515, 0.104, 0.896, 0.414, 0.586, 0.676, 0.324, 
0.333, 0.667, 0.6899, 0.3101, 0.99, 0.01, 0.99, 0.01, 0.4, 0.6, 
0.35, 0.65, 0.223, 0.777, 0.468, 0.532, 0.149, 0.851, 0.99, 0.01, 
0.4, 0.6, 0.99, 0.01, 0.99, 0.01, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.771, 
0.229, 0.99, 0.01, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.43, 0.57, 
0.46, 0.54, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.99, 0.01), g = c("13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", 
"13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x", "13907   x")), row.names = c(NA, 
-190L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(
    p = c(67500055, 67500055, 77700108, 77700108, 77700133, 77700133, 
    77700135, 77700135, 77700137, 77700137, 77700139, 77700139, 
    104300134, 104300134, 357300053, 357300053, 357300054, 357300054, 
    357300067, 357300067, 357300070, 357300070, 357300072, 357300072, 
    357300078, 357300078, 357300079, 357300079, 357300093, 357300093, 
    574100025, 574100025, 581300127, 581300127, 990200002, 990200002, 
    1032400220, 1032400220, 3481000035, 3481000035, 3481000036, 
    3481000036, 3481000037, 3481000037, 5075700005, 5075700005, 
    6424000064, 6424000064, 6677700001, 6677700001, 6749600001, 
    6749600001, 6761900044, 6761900044, 7027100032, 7027100032, 
    7527700002, 7527700002, 8185700001, 8185700001, 9145200001, 
    9145200001, 9145200005, 9145200005, 9145200006, 9145200006, 
    9270800001, 9270800001, 9533700001, 9533700001), f = c("21801", 
    "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", 
    "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", 
    "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", 
    "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", 
    "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", 
    "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", 
    "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x", 
    "21801", "x", "21801", "x", "21801", "x"), x = c(0.025, 0.975, 
    0.035, 0.965, 0.0263, 0.9737, 0.025, 0.975, 0.0263, 0.9737, 
    0.0278, 0.9722, 0.37, 0.63, 0.045, 0.955, 0.06, 0.94, 0.015, 
    0.985, 0.018, 0.982, 0.045, 0.955, 0.06, 0.94, 0.045, 0.955, 
    0.06, 0.94, 0.08, 0.92, 0.00667, 0.99333, 0.25, 0.75, 0.06, 
    0.94, 0.006, 0.994, 0.006, 0.994, 0.006, 0.994, 0.06, 0.94, 
    0.137, 0.863, 0.94, 0.0600000000000001, 0.0625, 0.9375, 0.003, 
    0.997, 0.06, 0.94, 0.05, 0.95, 0.045, 0.955, 0.25, 0.75, 
    0.002, 0.998, 0.009, 0.991, 0.0066, 0.9934, 0.015, 0.985), 
    g = c("21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", 
    "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", 
    "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", 
    "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", 
    "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", 
    "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", 
    "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", 
    "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", 
    "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", 
    "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", 
    "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", 
    "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", 
    "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", 
    "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", "21801   x", 
    "21801   x")), row.names = c(NA, -70L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(p = c(1032400234, 1032400234, 
1032400234, 1032400234, 1032400234), f = c("21801", "69149", 
"69165", "69166", "169101"), x = c(0.3, 0.0154, 0.0307, 0.0154, 
0.041), g = c("21801 69149 69165 69166 169101", "21801 69149 69165 69166 169101", 
"21801 69149 69165 69166 169101", "21801 69149 69165 69166 169101", 
"21801 69149 69165 69166 169101")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(p = c(46400699, 46400699, 
46400700, 46400700, 46400701, 46400701, 46400702, 46400702, 46400712, 
46400712, 46400715, 46400715, 46400716, 46400716, 46408142, 46408142, 
183900249, 183900249, 183900251, 183900251, 183900252, 183900252, 
1032400207, 1032400207, 1032400222, 1032400222, 1032400223, 1032400223, 
1070700067, 1070700067, 5248400005, 5248400005, 7117300007, 7117300007, 
7117300009, 7117300009, 8276000005, 8276000005, 8911000022, 8911000022, 
9051100006, 9051100006, 9051100009, 9051100009, 9092400009, 9092400009, 
9251300001, 9251300001, 9251300002, 9251300002, 9251300003, 9251300003, 
9251300005, 9251300005, 9251300006, 9251300006, 9358500001, 9358500001, 
9460200002, 9460200002, 9460200003, 9460200003), f = c("43901", 
"69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", 
"43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", 
"69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", 
"43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", 
"69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", 
"43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", 
"69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", 
"43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", 
"69105", "43901", "69105", "43901", "69105"), x = c(0.14, 0.025, 
0.14, 0.025, 0.425, 0.075, 0.425, 0.075, 0.425, 0.075, 0.425, 
0.075, 0.14, 0.025, 0.14, 0.025, 0.14, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.425, 
0.075, 0.4, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.14, 0.025, 0.14, 0.03, 
0.14, 0.025, 0.425, 0.075, 0.14, 0.025, 0.14, 0.025, 0.14, 0.025, 
0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.12, 0.03, 0.25, 0.1, 0.048, 0.02, 0.05, 
0.1, 0.14, 0.025, 0.14, 0.025, 0.08, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1), g = c("43901 69105", 
"43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", 
"43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", 
"43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", 
"43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", 
"43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", 
"43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", 
"43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", 
"43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", 
"43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", 
"43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", 
"43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", 
"43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", "43901 69105", 
"43901 69105")), row.names = c(NA, -62L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))), ptype = structure(list(p = numeric(0), 
    f = character(0), x = numeric(0), g = character(0)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = integer(0)), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))
```

Comment: If you wrap the code block as a function and then use `lapply(dfl, yourfun)` woudn't that work or just use `map_dfr(dfl, yourfun)`

Comment: lapply followed by bind_rows?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the code as a function and use `map_dfr` to get all the output as a single data

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(cluster)
library(factoextra)
dfl <- list(datainput, datainput)
map_dfr(dfl, f1, .id = 'id')
# A tibble: 144 x 6
   id             p f           x g          cluster
   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>        <int>
 1 1      409100012 107403 0.005  107403   x       1
 2 1      409100012 x      0.995  107403   x       1
 3 1     1032400197 107403 0.05   107403   x       2
 4 1     1032400197 x      0.95   107403   x       2
 5 1     3725600001 107403 0.033  107403   x       2
 6 1     3725600001 x      0.967  107403   x       2
 7 1     4218200011 107403 0.036  107403   x       2
 8 1     4218200011 x      0.964  107403   x       2
 9 1     4873700001 107403 0.0512 107403   x       2
10 1     4873700001 x      0.949  107403   x       2
# … with 134 more rows
```

where

```
f1 <- function(dat) { 
  df <- pivot_wider( 
    dat,
    id_cols = "p", 
    names_from = "f", 
    values_from = "x"
  )
  
  rows <- df$p
  
  df <- df %>% select(-p) 
  
  df[is.na(df)] <- 0
  
  row.names(df) <- rows
  
  df <- scale(df)
  
  # compute dissimilarity matrix
  d <- dist(df, method = "euclidean")
  
  # store method names in m
  m <- c( "average", "single", "complete", "ward")
  names(m) <- c( "average", "single", "complete", "ward")
  
  # function to compute coefficients
  ac <- function(x) { 
    agnes(d, method = x)$ac
  }
  
  # choose best method by coefficient, store in method
  coeffs <- map_dbl(m, ac) %>% #
    as_tibble %>%
    mutate(method = m) %>%
    filter(value == max(value))
  
  coeffs <- matrix(data = coeffs)
  
  method = coeffs[2,1]
  
  # Function to compute hierarchical clustering using d and method
  hc <- function(x) {
    agnes(d, method = method)
  }
  
  # compute hierarchical clustering with optimal method
  hc1 <- hc(method)
  
  # determine optimal clusters number by slopes of elbow plot
  elbowplot <- fviz_nbclust(df, FUN = hcut, method = "wss")
  
  elbow <- ggplot_build(elbowplot)
  
  elbow <- elbow$data[[1]] %>%
    as_tibble() 
  
  elbow <- elbow %>%
    mutate(slope = if_else(
      elbow$x == min(elbow$x), elbow$y/elbow$x,
      -(elbow$y-lag(elbow$y)/(elbow$x-lag(elbow$x)))
    ))
  
  elbow <- elbow %>%
    mutate(lastslope = if_else(
      x == 1, slope, lag(elbow$slope)
    )) %>%
    mutate(nextslope = if_else(
      elbow$x == max(elbow$x), elbow$slope, lead(elbow$slope)
    )) %>%
    mutate(slopedelta = as.numeric(lastslope - slope)) %>%
    arrange(-slopedelta) %>%
    slice_head() %>%
    select(x)
  
  clusters <- matrix(data = elbow)
  
  clusters = clusters[1,1]
  
  # Cut dendrogram by clusters, store in sub_grp
  sub_grp <- cutree(hc1, k = clusters)
  
  # store cluster value as column called cluster
  df <- df %>%
    as_tibble()
  
  row.names(df) <- rows
  
  df <- df %>%
    rownames_to_column(var = "p") %>%
    mutate(cluster = sub_grp) %>%
    select(p, cluster) %>%
    mutate(p = as.double(p))
  
  dat <-
    left_join(dat, df)
  
  return(dat)
}
```